# Compare 5 k-mer vectors and find unique ones

Tags: r, compare, subset, sequence, bioinformatics

I have 5 different bacteria sequences and I found their subsequences by kmers. Now I have list of subsequences but I need to compare this lists to find unique ones. I mean a subsequence that be found in just 1 sequence,but is not found any other sequence. How I can compare these multiple subsequences ? 
PS: I will start from length=15 to find subsequence with min-length in the each sequence.

I got 5 k-mers of 5 different sequences. I have 5 lists that show any subsequence in length=15 and how much they found in the sequence. Now,I should compare these 5 lists and find unique ones.

```
##### First of all, I read the 5 different sequences from my PC. #


>
kmers1 = get.kmers(.data= mseq1, .head=-1, .k=15, .clean= T, .meat= F, .verbose= T, .left.shift=0, .right.shift=0)

>
kmers2 = get.kmers(.data= mseq2, .head=-1, .k=15, .clean= T, .meat= F, .verbose= T, .left.shift=0, .right.shift=0)

>
kmers3 = get.kmers(.data= mseq3, .head=-1, .k=15, .clean= T, .meat= F, .verbose= T, .left.shift=0, .right.shift=0)

>
kmers4 = get.kmers(.data= mseq4, .head=-1, .k=15, .clean= T, .meat= F, .verbose= T, .left.shift=0, .right.shift=0)

>
kmers5 = get.kmers(.data= mseq5, .head=-1, .k=15, .clean= T, .meat= F, .verbose= T, .left.shift=0, .right.shift=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what format your data are in but here is a method to find unique values in a list of subsequences:

```
# function to simulate random sequences of length n
sim_seq = function(n) paste(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 100, rep=T), collapse="")

# simulate 3 random sequences each 100 bases long 
seqs = lapply(c(100, 100, 100), sim_seq)

# function to split sequence into kmers of length n
kmer = function(x, n) sapply(1:(nchar(x)-n), function(i) substr(x, i, i + n)) 

# split seqs into kmers of length 5
kmer_list = lapply(seqs, kmer, 5)
```

EDIT 2

Ok I think I understand - does this work?

First make a list of the five sets of kmers. Call it kmer_list. Then use this lapply call to get a list of the unique subsequences within each 5 sequences.

kmer_list = list(kmer1, kmer2 ... )

```
unique_seqs = lapply(1:length(kmer_list), function(i){
  seq = kmer_list[[i]]
  target = unlist(kmer_list[-i])
  seq[!seq %in% target]
})
```

Comment: After that I wrote these codes to just have the subsequences;

list1 = kmers1[1]
list2 = kmers2[1]
list3 = kmers3[1]
list4 = kmers4[1]
list5 = kmers5[1]       ,, so I have 5 vectors like;
99960 TTTTTTCTTTCGGCC
99961 TTTTTTCTTTGATGG
99962 TTTTTTGACTCAAGG
99963 TTTTTTGAGTTTATT
99964 TTTTTTGATATCAAA
99965 TTTTTTGCGGGACCT
99966 TTTTTTGCGTACGTT
99967 TTTTTTGCTGGGGGA
99968 TTTTTTGGGTCGCTA
99969 TTTTTTGGTGGGGCG
99970 TTTTTTGTATAACTA
99971 TTTTTTGTCAATCAG
99972 TTTTTTTACGAGTTC
99973 TTTTTTTACTTCTAT
99974 TTTTTTTCTTTCGGC
99975 TTTTTTTGAGTTTAT
99976 TTTTTTTGATATCAA

Comment: I could not edit the comment and I know it looks awful. I hope you can understand.

Comment: Also, I want to compare these 5 different vectors. I should eliminate common ones and at the end I hope to have the unique ones. I wrote your code and it just shows one group's subsequences.

Comment: Ok so you want to a list of length five with the unique subsequences in each sequences? The code I wrote finds all unique subsequences and puts the together into one vector.

Comment: The numbers showing the showing their line number. I have got 96k k-mers from each of the sequence. I just copied last of them so they are last lines.

Comment: I want to list all 5 subsequences of 5 sequences and compare them. For example, I want to find  subsequences of first sequence that is not found in any other 4 sequences.

Comment: Sorry If you tried that code it may not have worked because I forgot to change the variable just_subseqs to kmer_list in the script .... should work now?

Comment: Yes it is worked but I don't know what should I write to show my unique sequence for each. I tried to write "seq" , "target" and "unique_seqs". Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to see the unique sequences for the first sequence then you write unique_seqs[[1]] and for the nth sequence unique_seqs[[n]].